# Excel VBA: Create a stacked column chart with named table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to create a stacked column graph using 3 columns of data out of a large ~30 column named table in excel. The desired outcome would be a stacked column graph, where the columns are based on the column "Program" (there are 5 distinct values across ~200 rows) and the numbers that make up the columns are the "SAVINGS - USE THIS" with the corresponding "Project Number"s as those chunks labels. Each row is a distinct project.

For instance, if I have 5 projects in "Program 1," I would want the "SAVINGS - USE THIS" values stacked on top of each other and when a run my mouse over the portions of the column the Project Number would show.

I am fairly new to VBA and am currently editing my previous code to make the project numbers and their savings into a pie graph (originally I didn't care about the program), so if there is a better way to do any of this please let me know.

```
Sub CreateChart()

Dim labelRng As Range
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim progRng As Range
Dim chtRng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim mySeries As Series
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set chtRng = Union(Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("Program").Range, _
            Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("Project Number").Range, _
            Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("SAVINGS - USE THIS").Range)
'Set progRng = Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("Program").Range
'Set labelRng = Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("Project Number").Range
'Set dataRng = Sheets("CMF").ListObjects("CMF").ListColumns("SAVINGS - USE THIS").Range
'Set chtRng = Union(progRng, dataRng, labelRng) 'Sets range for pie

Set cht = Sheets("CMF").Shapes.AddChart2 'Creates chart
For j = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1 'Had to be added to avoid errors
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete
Next j
cht.Chart.SetSourceData chtRng 'Sets data range for chart
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
```

If this is the best way to do this, my current issue is defining the data range for the graph. You can see I am trying a couple different things, but the problem I'm having is that instead of pulling the "Program" column it is pulling the column that is next to it.

For reference, Project Number is in Column A, Program is in Column C and SAVINGS is in column X. It is pulling Columns A, B and X. Even if I specify the column number as "3" or pull them in a different order, I always have the same issue. The only way I don't have the issue is if I stop pulling in the Project Number and just pull in Program and Savings, which it gets right.

What am I doing that is causing it to pull back the wrong column of data, and once I get the right data in how can I make the stacked columns be organized by Program?

Thanks for reading all of that!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just assigning `SetSourceData` at the end, excel is going to do what it thinks is best...which isn't what you want in this case.

Try creating the different Series one at a time and assigning the ranges for each individually after you delete them.  Just use the Macro Recorder to go over all the steps that you need to do to create the chart from scratch.